# New To Ubuntu - Hyper-V - Running out of Space?

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04, virtualization, hyper-v, vagrant

I am new to Ubuntu and since I was just laid off from my job of 17 years, I've decided to try to learn some new skills and bought the book, DevOps for the Desparate by Bradley Smith from No Starch Press.

I am using a Windows 11 Pro OS with Hyper-V to go through the tutorials and have created an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS virtual machine in Hyper-V, pulled the git repo, installed VirtualBox, Vagrant and Ansible.

The problem that I keep running into (I've been through this process a couple of times already) is that when I run

```
$vagrant up
```

The process ran for a bit but then I got a low disk space error on the Ubuntu VM where it said that there's only a few mb of space remaining which didn't make sense to me since I think the allocated HD space was 60GB.

[image]

So at this point, the VM crashed and when I tried to restart it and login, the VM seemed to hang and I finally got this error:

[image]

I saw some posts suggesting that remoting into the VM using WinSCP and inspecting some config settings, but couldn't understand if the machine wasn't booted, how that would be possible, so I figured the VM was just hosed and started over, when I went through the steps again and this time
I increased the hard drive to 100gb.

When I ran:

```
   $vagrant up
```

The process seemed to get a bit further but received the low disk space error on the Ubuntu VM  and the VM crashed again.

[image]

When it restarted, I attempted to login again but got the same Connection Log error message as shown in the screen shot above.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should help: See "Most Common Partition Scheme" in the Dell link below. See if you have a small partition as per the link and depending on the partition you may be able to increase it. https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000131456/the-types-and-definitions-of-ubuntu-linux-partitions-and-directories-explained https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemsExplained How To Resize Linux Partition Using Command Line - Computer How To https://arstech.net/resize-linux-partition-command-line/

Comment: Yes, but how can I resize the linux partition if I cannot login to the VM?

Comment: Use another VM and mount the vdisk there and resize it by first increasing the VHDx.  Have you tried to disable enhanced session to get in then if you want to use enhanced session later you can make sure all the correct prereqs are in place?